# Program working before assigning section of code into a subprogram

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

This is the error I am getting after assigning code into a subprogram

> "NameError: name 'P1D1' is not defined"

This is the code:

```
def dice_rolling():
    #stage 2 dice rolling
    #P1D1 means player ones dice one value and so on with P1D2
    import random
    #player ones turn
    print("player ones turn")
    P1D1 = random.randint (1,6)
    print ("your number is ",P1D1)
    P1D2 = random.randint (1,6)
    print ("your second number is",P1D2)
    #player twos turn
    print ("player twos turn")
    P2D1 = random.randint (1,6)
    print ("your number is" , P2D1)
    P2D2 = random .randint (1,6)
    print ("your second number is",P2D2)


def score_calculation():
    round_number = 0
    round_number = round_number + 1
    #player 1 score calculation
    total_P1 = P1D1 + P1D2
    P1_score = P1_score + total_P1
    if total_P1 % 2 == 0:
        P1_score = P1_score + 10
    else:
        P1_score = P1_score + 5
    if P1D1 == P1D2 :
        P1D3 = random.randint (1,6)
        P1_score = P1_score + P1D3

    #player 2 score calculation
    total_P2 = P2D1 + P2D2
    P2_score = P2_score + total_P2
    if total_P2 % 2 == 0:
        P2_score = P2_score + 10
    else:
        P2_score = P2_score + 5
    if P2D1 == P2D2 :
        P2D3 = random.randint (1,6)
        P2_score = P2_score + P2D3
    print("player ones score at the end of round ",round_number, "is" , P1_score)
    print(P2_score)

dice_rolling()
score_calculation()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you make variable in function `dice_rolling()` and then you try to use them in `score_calculation()` function.
you need to define global variables or define variables in `score_calculation()` function or you can pass this variables as arguments in `score_calculation()` function

```
import random


def dice_rolling():
    # P1D1 means player ones dice one value and so on with P1D2
    import random
    # player ones turn
    print("player ones turn")
    P1D1 = random.randint(1, 6)
    print("your number is ", P1D1)
    P1D2 = random.randint(1, 6)
    print("your second number is", P1D2)
    # player twos turn
    print("player twos turn")
    P2D1 = random.randint(1, 6)
    print("your number is", P2D1)
    P2D2 = random.randint(1, 6)
    print("your second number is", P2D2)
    score_calculation(P1D1, P1D2, P2D1, P2D2)


def score_calculation(P1D1, P1D2, P2D1, P2D2):
    round_number = 0
    round_number = round_number + 1
    # player 1 score calculation
    total_P1 = P1D1 + P1D2
    P1_score = total_P1
    if total_P1 % 2 == 0:
        P1_score = P1_score + 10
    else:
        P1_score = P1_score + 5
    if P1D1 == P1D2:
        P1D3 = random.randint(1, 6)
        P1_score = P1_score + P1D3

    # player 2 score calculation
    total_P2 = P2D1 + P2D2
    P2_score = total_P2
    if total_P2 % 2 == 0:
        P2_score = P2_score + 10
    else:
        P2_score = P2_score + 5
    if P2D1 == P2D2:
        P2D3 = random.randint(1, 6)
        P2_score = P2_score + P2D3


    print("player ones score at the end of round ", round_number, "is", P1_score)
    print(P2_score)

dice_rolling()
```

Comment: i tried this but to no avail im now getting the error "TypeError: score_calculation() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'P1D1', 'P1D2', 'P2D1', and 'P2D2'"

Comment: i updated my code. You try again. Please note that you need to call only dice_rolling() function. Like in my example on last line. Because score_calculation is now called from dice_rolling

Comment: where do you define P1_score and P2_score variables?

Comment: thank you very much i gave myself two other errors for not including/making global two other variables and not importing random into score calculation(edit i defined them at the start and didnt make them global)